# create xml from java using Jdom

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jdom, jdom-2

I'm using this code to create the generatedXml.xml file

```
Element FICHADAS = new Element("FICHADAS");
Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
doc.setRootElement(FICHADAS);
Element fichada = new Element("fichada");
fichada.addContent(new lement("N_Terminal").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Tarjeta").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Fecha").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Hora").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Causa").setText("XX"));
doc.getRootElement().addContent(fichada);
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("generatedXml.xml"));
```

But I get an error in the last line (I'm using eclipse):

> Multiple markers at this line - Unhandled exception type IOException -
>   Unhandled exception type IOException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be `throw` the `IOException` or you have to use a `try-catch-block` arround your code.

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
 ...
}
```

or

```
try{
Element FICHADAS = new Element("FICHADAS");
Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
doc.setRootElement(FICHADAS);
Element fichada = new Element("fichada");
fichada.addContent(new lement("N_Terminal").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Tarjeta").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Fecha").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Hora").setText("XX"));
fichada.addContent(new Element("Causa").setText("XX"));
doc.getRootElement().addContent(fichada);
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("generatedXml.xml"));
} catch(IOException){
  // handle the exception.

}
```

Comment: and it will create the generatedXml.xml?¿

Comment: @marcss if yo exception is thrown, yes.

Comment: and how can i know if yo exception will be thown

Comment: If you will add code in the catch block like `System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage())`, you will see it in the console if a exception is thrown.

Comment: I solved this part but now the console show me that:
Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.jdom2.IllegalAddException: The element "FICHADAS" could not be added as the root of the document: The Content already has an existing parent document